# NavigationView items not checking

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

In my `NavigationView`, I have most of my items divided into sections with subheaders. I'm achieving this by putting a `menu` inside an `item`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_top"
            android:title="@string/top"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_header"
            android:title="@string/header1">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_item1"
                    android:title="@string/item1"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_item2"
                    android:title="@string/item2"/>
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

However, this leads to the first item, `drawer_top`, being eternally checked. Other items are not checkable. My `onNavigationItemSelected`-Code looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    ... (navigate)
    return true;
}
```

Comment: SubMenuItems are not checkeable in `NavigationView`

Comment: @Moinkhan How would I lay out the menu so that they are checkable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that submenus are not checkable [by design](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175216#makechanges).

Here is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779679/android-supportdesign-navigationview-checked-menu-sub-items):

```
mNavigationView.getMenu().clear();
mNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_drawer);
mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(mNavItemId).setChecked(true);
```