# Sub menu using Navigation View don't get checked

Tags: android, material-design, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

I am using android design support library to create drawer layout.

In my `NavigationView` I have menu group which contains sub menu.

Here is my menu file.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
            android:title="Messages" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_friends"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_headset"
            android:title="Friends" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_discussion"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
            android:title="Discussion" />

        <item android:title="Sub Menus">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/sub_one"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
                    android:title="Sub item 1" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/sub_two"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                    android:title="Sub item 2" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
```

My item click listener

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                        Log.d("Item Click : ", menuItem.getTitle().toString());
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

**However my problem is only first four main menu items get checked properly while submenu click event also works but they don't get checked. Instead previous main menu remains checked.**

Comment: its is issue in design support lib check this, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178709  , if you still want to do then check answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31047154/1168654

Comment: Yes, it seem to be an issue in support library. But the link you have suggested is not a good solution because it inflates the menu each time we click on any item. So I am waiting for next library release by google

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but just noticed a solution. It is not pretty but works for me.

Does not seem like the single groups with checkableBehavior="single" would interact but they do. There´s just one item checked at a time but I also use two menus. Check this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group> 
    <item android:title="title">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
                    android:title="title"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
                    android:title="title"/> 
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_item_3"      
                    android:title="title"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="@string/title">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_1"
                    android:title="title"/> 
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_2"
                    android:title="title"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

But it doesn´t work with default xml state checked="true". In that case it doesn´t uncheck this item but check a second item in a single-checkable group. :D

Answer (score 2):

It acts with your sub items as one item and tries to highlight the entire thing. You want to single behavior as a group for the subitems. See below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
        android:title="Home" />
  <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_check"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cloud_queue_black_24dp"
        android:title="Check" />
</group>

<!-- Sub items -->

<item android:title="Other">
  <menu>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
      <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
            android:title="settings" />
      <item
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
          android:title="forum" />
    </group>
  </menu>
</item>
```